# How to backup my new laptop after I caught a hacker/identity theft in action without losing all of the evidence when I erase to factory default

Tags: windows

How can I backup my new laptop after I caught a hacker/identity theft in action without losing all of the evidence when I erase to factory default.

I literally just bought the laptop. I can not afford it because of an identity theft has taken everything from me and it took me one day to catch them already getting in just as they have all my phones , etc. I need to restore the PC to factory default and return it immediately so I can live a while being able to provide the authorities with information of the attacker?

Comment: We are going to need more information. Is the evidence pictures, logs, or something else? What operating system are you using? Provide as much as possible :)

Comment: Make 1:1 copy of your disk. Probably use some usb stick with linux and copy it on external hard disk

Comment: Personally I would just hand the laptop over to the police and let them work their magic. Making any changes risks losing any integrity of the evidence.

Comment: A copy using `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/mnt/externaldrive/some_image.img` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Magic-sudo's idea of making a 1:1 copy of the hard drive is good and basically feasible - this is what a digital forensic analyst would probably do as a first step in order not to mess with the actual laptop. You can achieve this with a Linux live USB stick and the 'dd' command. The next thing he'd do is calculate the fingerprint of both the original laptop HD and the copy, to prove that they're identical.

BUT - if you then reset your laptop to factory default, YOU'VE LOST YOUR PRIMARY EVIDENCE. Digital forensic analysts go through all this trouble of copying the device data so they don't need to touch the actual evidence, which could corrupt the evidence otherwise. they need the original to remain untainted so any evidence they find can be independently verified by other analysts if necessary. If you wipe your laptop, you still have a digital copy of the hard drive, but it will be impossible to prove that this is a copy of the state your laptop hard drive was in right before you factory-reset everything if you don't get some kind of legal certification that it is, *before* you factory-reset. It might even be impossible to prove that the copy you made came from your laptop at all. Basically, you break the chain of evidence if you do anything else than turn your laptop over to the police as Terry suggests.

So you'll have to decide what's more important: Have a chance to bring your identity thief to justice (which will probably be very difficult, but depending on what evidence is on your laptop hard drive, it might be possible), or get back the use of your laptop immediately. If you turn it over to the police, you should probably forget about getting it back anytime soon.